# Doubly linked list crash in C

Tags: c

hi i try this to run this code on VS 2010 and i get crash its tell me that:

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in TEST_5.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while TEST_5.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
The program '[4620] TEST_5.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

and i have same crash on borland c compiler,but in dev cpp its work.
so this is my code Please help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int ID;
    int active;
    int loop_time;
    float c;
    int a;
    struct node *prev,*next;
};
struct node *new_node(struct node *p)
{
    struct node *temp,*prev;
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        p=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
        p->prev=NULL;
        p->next=NULL;
        return p;
    }
    if(p!=NULL)
    {
        temp=p;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            prev=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
        temp->prev=prev;
        temp->next=NULL;
        prev->next=temp;
        return temp;
    }
    return 0;
}
void main()
{
    struct node *force1=NULL;
    //=============================
    force1=new_node(force1);
    force1->ID=11;
    force1->active=11;
    force1->loop_time=0;
    //==============================
    force1=new_node(force1);
    force1->ID=11;
    force1->active=11;
    force1->loop_time=0;
    //==============================
    printf("END\n");
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Where does it crash? What did you find while debugging?

Answer (score 4):

```
    p=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
```

and

```
    temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
```

should be

```
p=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

or even better

```
p=malloc(sizeof *p);
temp=malloc(sizeof *temp);
```

You are just allocating enough for a pointer, not for an entire struct.

Note that the first return from `new_node()` is leaked; there is no way to get to it after the second `new_node()` call returns.

Comment: +1 for good answer. To piggyback, OP may also want to look into deallocating memory at some point. The program as it stands has memory leakage; although it's not a problem for this small example.